# Two conditions in ARM Template to create a policy

Tags: json, azure

I am trying to create a policy to enforce both `soft-deletion` and `purge-protection` on Azure Key-Vaults. *There could be vaults with soft delete either enabled or disabled. Purge-Protection will be disabled*. Is it possible to do it in the same template? Something like this

```
{
  "field": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/enableSoftDelete",
  "equals": "true"
},
OR (How to do this?)
{
  "field": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/enableSoftDelete",
  "exists": "false"
},
{
  "field": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/enablePurgeProtection",
  "exists": "false"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to use the "anyOf" Opertaor.

```
 {
   "anyOf": [
     {
       "field": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/enableSoftDelete",
       "equals": "true"
     },
    
     {
       "field": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/enableSoftDelete",
       "exists": "false"
     }
   ]
 }
```